# Ubuntu 17.10 is not recognizing my wifi adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, 17.10

I've recently bought a new laptop, an [HP 15q-bu004TU](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05638249). I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 on it. It didn't detect the wifi networks both during and after the installation. When I checked the settings, I got the following message.

[image: No Wi-Fi Adapter Found]

I then tried to install the additional drivers by searching the **Software & Updates** tool, but I couldn't find any drivers related to the WiFi Adapter.

When I tried

```
    sudo lshw -C network
```

I got the following output:

```
    *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 15
   serial: 48:ba:4e:1e:1f:ea
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.10.9.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:126 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff

    *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

I don't know how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

The output of

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

is as follows

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try finding the drivers for your wireless network adapter. There are a lot of threads related to Ubuntu not recognizing Wi-Fi adapters, and the most simple solution is to install the drivers and it will hopefully work. If it doesn't, check these threads. Search in the AskUbuntu forum and find some that might help you.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: @chili555 I've edited my question as per your instructions

Comment: Jeremy31's now deleted answer is quite correct. Your device is not yet supported in Linux by any known means. Please see: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367405 and also: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/265 We are sorry that there is no better solution.

Comment: @chili555 I'll try something else then. Thank you for your help.